# Evenly space links in div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm making a simple website for college, which I hate, due to the designing. I'm a php programmer not a designer. (May sound stupid)

I have run into a problem, I have a centered div of 600px then inside `<nav>` tags I have 4 links. I would like them evenly spaced out, across the div. I have tried setting the margin-left and right but had no luck.

Take a look at it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/8jK7N/)

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being a programmer who dislikes design. But it's always good to have an understanding of both sides. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8jK7N/1/

IE, however, doesn't support styling of the new HTML5 elements. You can use shiv to solve this issue. Working demo (with shiv): http://jsfiddle.net/8jK7N/2/

Answer (score 1):

Take the `<p>` tag out of the `<nav>` bit, also margin-left 73px and margin-right 73px on each may make the links too wide for one line in your div. I know the math works out but it may be acting strangely.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the margin-right on the `nav a` it will work.  The added spacing on the margin-right is added to the box of the anchor.  Here is how the box model works: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

*Note in IE the html5 nav selector doesn't seem to not work correctly.*  I added a class on the paragraph tag and applied the fix that that tag.

This is what will work in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/RkUWU/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
nav a{
    width:150px; display:block;float:left;
}
```

If you want then centered, add:

```
text-align:center;
```